# How do I create dynamically named folders with Maven Archetype?

Tags: maven-2, maven-archetype

I'm trying to build an archetype structure like this, a webapp with some custom folders for our web framework. Especially some dynamic folders which also will contain some files brought by the archetype.

```
└───src
    └───main
        └───webapp
            └───WEB-INF
                ├───cfg
                │   ├───log4j
                │   └───resources
                │       └───extensions
                │           ├───${shortName}-business
                │           └───${shortName}-layout
                └───lib
```

I added a required property to my `archetype-metadata.xml` to have an short name for the project, which is used among other things for generating unique folders.

```
<requiredProperties>
  <requiredProperty key="shortName" />
</requiredProperties>
```

The property `shortName` I use in a `fileSet`:

```
<fileSet>
  <directory>[..]/resources/extensions/${shortName}-business</directory>
</fileSet>

<fileSet>
  <directory>[..]/resources/extensions/${shortName}-layout</directory>
</fileSet>
```

---

The command to generate the archetype:

```
mvn archetype:generate -B \
       -DgroupId=com.stackoverflow \
       -DartifactId=stackoverflow-question -DarchetypeGroupId=com.stackoverflow \
       -DarchetypeArtifactId=stackoverflow-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=1.0 \
       -DshortName=soq
```

I assume to get the following folder structure:

```
..\
   ├───soq-business
   └───soq-layout
```

But I get this name `${shortName}-business` as folder, without  it being replaced with the property.

```
..\
   ├───${shortName}-business
   └───${shortName}-layout
```

How can I achieve this? How can I place files below `soq-business` without knowing the folder name at this time?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I figured the exact same problem today...

I found some blog entry by Adam Leggett which describes using placeholders in paths: have a look at https://mikeciblogs.wordpress.com/2010/01/14/working-with-custom-maven-archetypes-part-1/ (Step 4).

The trick seems to be to use doubled underscores instead of the curly braces syntax, so `${shortName}` becomes `__shortName__`.

However, I haven't tried the solution yet. If you do so, please let us know if it works. Thanks!

HTH!

Comment: The Blog is not available. Maybe the link is broken, could someone update it please!

Answer (score 4):

As Vivian has kindly pointed out, my blog entry provides some hints on how to do this.
However, one thing to watch out for (which isn't explicitly mentioned in the blog) is that this feature only works with the archetype plugin 2.x